# nGinx rewrite on location with condition

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

We're using nginx for a website with multiple languages. We need to add a language for only one sub-site url and the rest have to been redirect. Something like this:

```
location /eu/ {
    if ($request_uri !~* "/(eu/sub-site/)") {
        rewrite ^/eu/(.*)$ /es/request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

But the rewrite didn't work.

Comment: `the rewrite didn't work` doesn't tell us much - what happened?

Comment: For example, whe going to: /eu/ramblas/habitaciones/ didn't rewrite to
/es/ramblas/habitaciones/ what is that we spected.

Comment: You still didn't tell us what happened.  What does `didn't rewrite` mean?  Simply nothing happened, you stayed on the original URI?  Some errors?  You were redirected to a different URL than expected?

Comment: No redirects are aplied, the URL is the same. 
The behavior we expect is:
When going to:
/eu/ramblas/habitaciones/ must be redirect to /es/ramblas/habitaciones/. This behavior has to been aplied to other URL, like /eu/ramblas/info/ rewrite to /es/ramblas/info/ or /eu/madrid/ rewrite to /es/madrid/.
When going to /eu/sub-site/ no rewrites have to been aplied

Comment: You are rewriting `/eu/foo` to `/es/eu/foo`. If you are intending to rewrite to `/es/foo` you should use the capture. For example: `rewrite ^/eu/(.*)$ /es/$1 permanent;`